# While I was coding java using JOptionPane I couldn't understand below line

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component compt, Object o, String string, int i, Icon icon);
```

in the above line I didn't understood any parameters and also I provided string in the place of object
and it stills works. Can anybody explain correct procedure.

Comment: String is an object. Also refer to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) to understand the parameters.

Comment: Simply read java documentation : Object[]
An array of objects is interpreted as a series of messages (one per object) arranged in a vertical stack. The interpretation is recursive -- each object in the array is interpreted according to its type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29)

- **parentComponent** - determines the Frame in which the dialog is displayed; if null, 
   or if the    parentComponent has no Frame, a default Frame is used
- **message** - the Object to display
- **title** - the title string for the dialog
- **messageType** - the type of message to be displayed: `ERROR_MESSAGE, INFORMATION_MESSAGE, WARNING_MESSAGE, QUESTION_MESSAGE, or PLAIN_MESSAGE`
- **icon** - an icon to display in the dialog that helps the user identify the kind of message that is being displayed